# При наведении на блок с картинками происходило бы изменение позиционирования

Tags: html, jquery, css

Необходимо, чтобы при наведении на блок с картинками - картинки два раза прыгнули к верху на `3px`. а потом вернулись на место за `500 ms .`

```js
var box = $('.box');

box.mousemove(function Newbox() {
  box.css('marginTop', '3px');
});

setTimeout(Newbox, 300);
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/evil-icons-user-interface/64/arrow_down2-32.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/evil-icons-user-interface/64/arrow_down2-32.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/evil-icons-user-interface/64/arrow_down2-32.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю на кой тебе JQ

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.anim:hover {
  animation: up .5s linear;
}

@keyframes up {
  from {
    margin-top: -3px;
  }
  25% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: -3px;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box anim">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/evil-icons-user-interface/64/arrow_down2-32.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/evil-icons-user-interface/64/arrow_down2-32.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/evil-icons-user-interface/64/arrow_down2-32.png" alt="">
</div>
```